# Extract data from Parse PFObject in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, xcode5, pfquery

I am using Parse.com for storing data in my app.
I have a class on Parse named TestScore. Which has tested, score and username fields. 
Now I want to get top 5 scorers and save them into NSUserDefaults.
Here is my code

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestScore"];
[query whereKey:@"test" equalTo:test];
[query orderByDescending:@"score"];
query.limit = 5;

NSMutableArray *top5Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
if (!error)
{
    NSMutableArray *score = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *userName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (PFObject *object in objects)
    {
        [score addObject:[object valueForKey:@"score"]];
        [userName addObject:[object valueForKey:@"userName"]];
    }
    [top5Array addObject:score];
    [top5Array addObject:userName];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:top5Array forKey:@"Top5"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error while getting top 5 Scorers.");
}}];
```

But, unfortunately its not working. I debugged through it and actually control does not go query block.
Can anyone help, please!

Comment: Have you successfully tried other queries with Parse within your app?

Comment: Remember that code runs in the background on a separate thread, so it could take a while to actually go into the block. Did you do [Parse setClientId:applicationId:] in your app delegate?

Comment: @pixelcdv Yes i have successfully tried some queries before.

Comment: @Eric Amorde Yes I did set AppID and ClientKey

Comment: Looking at your code, It should work. What comes to my mind is that `test` is not the same data type as the key of the Parse class you're querying against. Also, in your block, verify that the `objects` NSArray contains something: `if (!error && [objects count]){}`.

Comment: In your `for (PFObject *object in objects)` loop, I would `NSlog` the keys of the `PFObject` returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `top5Array` as a block variable:

```
__block NSMutableArray *top5Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

"Actually you can save a custom object to NSUserDefaults, but you must first convert it into NSData using NSKeyedArchiver. For that to work, your custom object must implement the NSCoding protocol. Take a look at this library I created that adds NSCoding support to Parse objects:

https://github.com/martinrybak/Parse-NSCoding

Martin Rybak
"

Please refer to the original of the above mentioned solution at the link below

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-save-parse-returned-data-into-nsuserdefaults